# Creating Node-Red custom node: config not working, shows a textbox instead of the configs drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-red

I am currently trying to create a custom node for a personal project. I need to save the configuration of my server, so I want to use a [config node](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/config-nodes)

The problem is, that instead of seeing the config selector in the "node properties" of my custom node, I only see a textbox.

This is an extract of my package.json file:

```
"node-red": {
    "nodes": {
      "authentication": "authentication-node/authentication.js",
      "accessconfig": "configuration-node/configuration.js"
    }
}
```

My configuration.js file:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
/*
Configuration node functions
*/
function ConfigurationNode(n) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this,n);
    this.username = n.username;
    this.password = n.password;
}
RED.nodes.registerType("accessconfig",ConfigurationNode,{
    credentials: {
        username: {type:"text"},
        password: {type:"password"}
    }
});
}
```

My configuration.html file:

```
<!--Config node-->
<script type="text/javascript">
RED.nodes.registerType('accessconfig',{
    category: 'config',
    defaults: {
        name: {value:""}
    },
    credentials: {
        service-username: {type:"text"},
        service-password: {type:"password"}
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="accessconfig">
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="node-config-input-name"><i class="icon-tag"></i>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="node-config-input-name">
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="node-config-input-username"><i class="icon-tag"></i>Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="node-config-input-username">
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="node-config-input-password"><i class="icon-tag"></i>Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="node-config-input-password">
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-help-name="accessconfig">
<p>Help text.</p>
</script>
```

My authentication.js file:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
/*
Authentication node functions
*/
function AuthenticationNode(config) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
    var node = this;
    // Retrieve the configuration node
    node.configuration = RED.nodes.getNode(config.configuration);
    if (node.configuration) {
    } else {

    }
}
RED.nodes.registerType("authentication",AuthenticationNode);
}
```

My authentication.html file:

```
<!-- Authentication node-->
<script type="text/javascript">
RED.nodes.registerType('authentication',{
    category: 'test',
    color: '#a6bbcf',
    defaults: {
        name: {value:""},
        configuration: {value:"",type:"accessconfig",required:true}
    },
    inputs:0,
    outputs:0,
    icon: "file.png",
    label: function() {
        return this.name||"Authentication";
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="authentication">
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="node-input-name"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="node-input-name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="node-input-configuration">Configuration</label>
    <input type="text" id="node-input-configuration">
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-help-name="authentication">
<p>Help text.</p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I will post this here if anyone struggles with the same problem as me. It seems that the problem was in the name of the configs credentials ("service-username" and "service-password"). When I changed them to "username" and "password" all worked as expected.